# Counter in Java JsonPath expression

Tags: java, variables, expression, counter, jsonpath

I am trying to use counter in JSON Path expression and getting JSONPath error java.lang.numberFormatException

```
    for (int counter = 0; counter < ids.size(); counter++) {
        tmp_rules = JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[counter].rule");
        for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < tmp_rules.size();counter2++){
            if (
                    (JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[counter].rule[counter2]") == 1) &&
                    (JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[counter].asked[counter2]")) != 0) {
                       end_id.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..id[counter]"));
                       end_rule.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[counter].rule[counter2]"));
                       end_asked.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile,"$..orders[counter].asked[counter2]"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON path expressions are not valid, since you use `counter` and `counter2` strings as indexing arrays. You should rather use the *values* of your loop variables in the path expressions:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < ids.size(); counter++) {
    tmp_rules = JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[" + counter + "].rule");
    for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < tmp_rules.size();counter2++){
        if (
                (JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[" + counter + "].rule[" + counter2 + "]") == 1) &&
                (JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[" + counter + "].asked[" + counter2 + "]")) != 0) {
                   end_id.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..id[" + counter + "]"));
                   end_rule.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$..orders[" + counter + "].rule[" + counter2 + "]"));
                   end_asked.add(JsonPath.read(jsonFile,"$..orders[" + counter + "].asked[" + counter2 + "]"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this today. Now i have java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List...